# how can I access highscores of facebook friends playing my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have basic facebook integration in my app for posting screenshots. I would like to know how I could  achieve the following.

1. How can I save highscores of my iOS app users to be recognized by (or pushed to) facebook?
2. How can I retrieve these highscores of facebook friends playing my iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own highscore system, or you can use the Scores API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores

See "Read scores for players and friends":

> You can read the set of scores for a player and their friends by issuing an HTTP GET request to /APP_ID/scores with the user access_token for that app. The user_friends permission is required in order to view friends' scores. This returns a list of scores for a player and friends who have authorized the app. The list is sorted by descending score value, so it returns friends with the highest scores first. You can use this call to generate a leader board for a player and friends.